# C - what is the problem in the Return part of recursion in this code?

Tags: c

```
/* Recursive v. Iterative Fibonacci
 * simple recursion
 * Sally Coder Jan 18, 2018
 F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n — 2); F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1 */

#include <stdio.h>

long fibonacci(int n) {
  long f2 = 0, f1 = 1, f_old;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    f_old = f2;
    f2 = f2 + f1;
    f1 = f_old;
  }
  return f2;
}

long recursive_fibonacci(int n) {
  if (n <= 1)
    return n;
  else
    return (recursive_fibonacci(n — 1) + recursive_fibonacci(n — 2));
}

int main(void) {
  int how_many = 0, i;
  printf("I want table of fibonacci up to n:");

  scanf("%d", &how_many);
  printf("\n fibonacci\n");

  for (i = 0; i < how_many; i++)
    printf("\n%d\t %1d %1d\n", i, fibonacci(i), recursive_fibonacci(i));
}
```

I am getting an error in the return statement of the function `recursive_fibonacci()` code.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: *"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"* means that your post has too much code, and not enough information. It means you should add more details about what you are asking. It does not mean to pad your question with spam.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is in the line `return (recursive_fibonacci(n — 1) + recursive_fibonacci(n — 2));`.

Specifically, the symbols you used `—` in `n — 1` and `n — 2` are not subtraction "`-`"operator.

Just delete the symbols `—` and retype them properly. This type of problem does occur when you copy code from some online blog.